# Difference between WCF rest starter kit and Web Application Toolkit for REST Services

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

Whats the difference between http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WebAppToolkitREST and http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/wcf-rest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the first time I have come across the `Web Application Toolkit for REST services`.  After downloading it and sniffing around, it appears to be more of a sample application that shows you how to use the WCF REST capabilities that were released in .NET 3.5.

The WCF REST Starter kit built on top of the REST library in .net 3.5 to make it easier to produce REST services.  In my opinion, `WCF REST Starter kit Preview 2` has been completely replaced by the capabilities that are in .Net 4.0.

In summary the toolkit is a set of samples that show you how you can use WCF REST in .Net 3.5.  WCF REST Starter kit was a set of experimental extensions that have been released in .Net 4.

Comment: +1 for "WCF REST Starter kit Preview 2 has been completely replaced by the capabilities that are in .Net 4.0". Thanks for confirming this. MSDN pages still treat it as current.

Comment: @greg Actually, my statement was not completely true.  The client side stuff never made it into .net 4.  Check out http://wcf.codeplex.com for the latest developments in this area.  Also look out for more announcements at Build next week.

Answer (score 0):

The Web Application Toolkit for REST services allows for ASP.NET and AJAX clients to call RESTful services, where as the WCF REST Starter kit allows you to create and consume RESTful services using WCF.

Comment: Nope. Both uses WCF.

Web Application Toolkit for REST Services says "It exposes an API using REST services built with the Windows Communication Foundation that can consumed by client applications"

WCF-REST Starter Kit is all about WCF.

Comment: Sorry, but no. Quoute: "This Web Application Toolkit shows how to easily add REST service interfaces for an existing Web application" Both can be used to create WCF Rest services.